# getting system date(int & char mixed) using sscanf

Tags: c

I am trying to include system date in a program, which would calculate the total value of days since 2000. So that I could compare values of various dates (like- Antivirus update date, OS updation date) with it in order to find what is the delay in system updation. The procedure of finding date in C was killing me so I used system command to find out the current date.

```
    system("date/t > system_date.txt");
```

I want to read the date from this file. There was no problem if the date was all in digits(ex.- 03/09/13). But the date displayed from DOS is of type : 03-Sep-13 . If I use sscanf as follows:

```
    FILE *fp_date=fopen("system_date.txt","r");
    char buffer[11];   int day,yr;   char yr[3];
    fgets(buffer,11,fp_date);
    sscanf("%d-??????-%d",&day,&mon,&yr);
```

Now how do I scan these separately with their data types? I don't know what to use in place of ??????. Or the other method which I have been using is to store whole line in an array, then run for loops to get elements separated by '-'. But I just wanted to be a bit more sophisticated. Thanks...

Comment: What is the problem? You seem to already know how to get their data types, using `%d` for `int`. Since the month is listed as a string, you should use `%s` there, then perform some quick analysis to figure out which month it is as an integer.

Comment: If "the procedure of finding date in C was killing" you, this is clearly not a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `system` (and not even the `date` command). BTW, using `popen("date","r")` might be simpler but is still not the right way.

Read first the [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html) man page.

Then use code like

```
  time_t now=0;
  time (&now);
  struct tm* ltm = localtime(&now);
```

The [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html) syscall gives the time from the Unix [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (start of 1970 year) in seconds. Use [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) if you want more precision (or measure CPU, or thread, time). [gettimeofday(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html) is becoming obsolete. [localtime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html) converts a Unix time to a `struct tm` containing seconds, minutes, ... day of week, day of month, month, .... fields.  Use `mktime` for the opposite conversion of a `struct tm` to a `time_t`. And `time_t` is also given by other functions or syscalls (like [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) giving metadata about a file, including its modification time).

You can use fields from `ltm` programmatically like `ltm->tm_sec` for seconds, `ltm->tm_min` for minutes, .... `ltm->tm_mon`for month (0 for January, etc...), etc....

If you want a string, use [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) like

```
  char timebuf[32];
  strftime (timebuf, sizeof(timbuf), "%d %b %Y", ltm);
```

<sup>The opposite function is [strptime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) which parses a string into a `struct tm`.</sup>

Notice that `strftime` use localization (see [locale(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html) first). So your user could get a french abbreviated month from `%b` (if his system is localized for French).

If you want universal (so called GMT) time, use `gmtime` instead of `localtime`. In multithreaded programs use `localtime_r` a,d `gmtime_r` and give them your own `struct tm`.

Comment: Thanks alot... You guys solved my problem. Thanks for sparing your time.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this. Obtaining the current date/time in C is trivial:

```
#include <time.h>
/* ... */
struct tm *tm = localtime(time(0));
```

The way you're trying to do it is much harder, not to mention error-prone. (For example, what happens if two instances run at the same time and both try to write to the same file?) In general, `system` is always the wrong way to do something.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that.  Just use [`time(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time) (C89) or [`gettimeofday(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gettimeofday) (POSIX) to get the current system time in [Unix time format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  If you need to convert that to other forms like a string representation or a `struct tm` object, then you can use various conversion functions such as [`ctime(3)`, `gtime(3)`, and `localtime(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime).

```
#include <time.h>

time_t now = time(NULL);
printf("The current time is: %s\n", ctime(&now));  // Warning: not thread-safe

struct tm *now_tm = localtime(now);  // Warning: not thread-safe
printf("Year=%d month=%d day=%d\n hour=%d minute=%d second=%d",
       1900 + now_tm->tm_year,
       1 + now_tm->tm_mon,
       now_tm->tm_mday,
       now_tm->tm_hour,
       now_tm->tm_min,
       now_tm->tm_sec);
```

Comment: Notice that `gettimeofday` is becoming obsolete. Today, better use `clock_gettime`

Comment: Guys, can you guide me regarding time on windows machine? This time is ok for linux, but when I run the code on windows machine, it doesn't work.

Comment: @kriss: That code should be perfectly fine for Windows. If you've got a problem using it, ask a new question.